# Can you give me an example of any PKC encrytion algorithm with coins?

Tags: public-key, reference-request

I'm reading a Definition of Public Key Encryption and here say:

> ...
>   Enc is a (possibly) probabilistic polynomial time encryption algorithm which takes as input a public key $pk$, a $m\in M$ and random coins $r$, and outputs a ciphertext $c\in C$.

But in other papers, there is no mention of coins $r$.

Can you give me examples of PKC  encrytion algorithms with coins?

Answer (score 2):

All textbook PKC systems are never applied as they are described. Take e.g: RSA.
There is a random padding technique that plays the role of the coins. The coins make the scheme probabilistic. For the same reason a block cipher which is instatiated as a pseudorandom permutations takes as input an instatiation vector IV. [OAEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_Asymmetric_Encryption_Padding) is a commonly used random encoding scheme before applying RSA on your data.

Answer (score 1):

Informally, we often say that a probabilistic algorithm is allowed to "toss a coin". Technically, we say that the algorithm has a random tape containing bits that have been chosen randomly. This random tape contains its "coin tosses" or just "coins".

Of course, any such algorithm can also be turned into a deterministic algorithm that in addition to its normal inputs also takes a bit string (of suitable length) as input, and uses this bit string as its random tape, or "coins". If we run this alternative algorithm with a random bit string as input, we get the exact same effect as we do when running the original algorithm (that has its own per-execution random tape).

Which means that any public key cryptosystem with a probabilistic encryption algorithm uses "coins", but it may not be described in those terms.

In cryptography, it is sometimes convenient to do use this alternative representation. For instance, if we have a public key cryptosystem with an encryption algorithm $\mathcal{E}(ek, m; r)$, we can turn this into a commitment scheme. To commit to a message $m$, choose a random string $r$ and compute the commitment $c$ as $\mathcal{E}(ek, m; r)$. To open the commitment, reveal $m$ and $r$.

If you use the traditional formulation of $\mathcal{E}$ as a probabilistic algorithm, the construction doesn't make sense.

Note that I've skipped some rather important details about key generation in the example.

Comment: This answer doesn't follow the question. You don't give any PKC that tosses coins.

Comment: Pick any secure public key cryptosystem. It tosses coins. (It may not be described in those terms, but it can be.) I'll amend the answer.

Comment: I don't disagree that any PKC does toss coins. But the question is different

Comment: @curious take ElGamal encryption, there you toss coins in order to generate your ephemeral (randomizer) $k$. Recall, if we have ElGamal in $Z_p^*$ and let $y=g^x$ the public key, then we encrypt a message $m$ by computing $(c_1,c_2)=(g^k,my^k)$ with $k$ randomly selected from $Z_p$. This can be viewed as "coin tosses".

Comment: Sorry i think you don't understand what i am saying.The question says describe me a PKC that toss coins doesn't say re-explain me the

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood you. @juaninf if you provide the coins $r$ externally, i.e., write $E(k,m;r)$ then the encryption algorithm itself is deterministic (you provide the randomness) but the encryption is still probabilistic. If you write $E(k,m)$ and speak of probabilistic encryption, then you assume that the coin tosses are handled by the probabilistic encryption algorithm. Back to my example: you may write ElGamal encryption as $E(y,m,k)$ or $E(y,m)$. Former is typically used if you want to control the randomness outside of the algorithm (for instance compute it pseudorandomly)

Comment: @K.G. Sorry but i think you don't understand my words. The question says clearly:"Can you give me examples of PKC encrytion algorithms with coins?" And my comment is that you didn't give any PKC that tosses coins. I am not arguing technically that all PKC tosses coins but you don't answer to the question.You are re-explaining that PKC tosses coins without giving concrete examples. Am i clear now?